# Colspan and Rowspan MediaWiki if function table

Tags: templates, mediawiki, iif-function

I´d like to know how I can use colspan and rowspan in media wiki if-functions, in a template? The colspan or rowspan shouldn´t be conditional.

Comment: Please rephrase, it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Ok, I am using this if-function:                                                                     {{#if:{{{Name|}}}|
{{!}} '''Name'''
{{!}} {{{Name|}}}
}}                                                                                                                             Since I am using it in a table, where some of the rows under the "Name" row conditionally expand to 4 columns, I´d like to use colspan in the row "Name". But I don´t now how to include it into the if-function.

Comment: `{{#if:{{{Name|}}}| {{!}} colspan="2" {{!}} '''Name''' {{!}}{{!}} {{{Name|}}} }}` (Your example is wrong, btw; the second `{{!}}}` must be doubled.)